# Suggestions for books on uniform and non-uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, resource-recommendations, vectors

With this question I am searching for a universitary or school book where the uniform and non-uniform circular motion is fully treated. I was interested if you could give me some specific details of the reason of the existence of these cross products:

$$\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{r}, \quad \text{ and } \quad \boldsymbol{a}_{\text{cp}}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{v}$$

and the acceleration of Coriolis. I have looked the following texts but I have found very few details.

*Related books where I have searched but I have finded a bit of the argument*:

Halliday-Resnick, Walker, Zemanski-Young-Fredmann, Serway, Tipler.

Comment: Is it possible that when I ask a question I must had, sometimes, negative votes?

Comment: I do not think you will find a more detailed treatment than those in the books you named, there is not much more depth to it

Comment: Yes it is possible that you sometimes get down voted but it just depends on what the voter thinks about your question. You shouldn't be much bothered about that.

Comment: @JohanLiebert I thank you for your kindness. But if I have included this comment, it is because every time I ask a question there is always someone who votes against me, not permitting to me, in the future, to ask other questions.

Comment: Don't worry this has been made a community-wiki it won't affect you now.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to find which is not already in the books you have mentioned. Book recommendations are often subjective - what works for others might not work for you. Suggestions with previews and reviews are easily found using a search engine. In addition there are many internet tutorials on this topic - eg [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-physics-1/ap-centripetal-force-and-gravitation/centripetal-acceleration-ap/v/visual-understanding-of-centripetal-acceleration-formula).